# WCF service request limit

Tags: 2010, development, web-services, wcf

I have setup a WCf service in my project using this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff521581.aspx

However, I'm POSTing lots of byte[] data to the service tocreate a file.  I basically have a canvas drawing, which I convert to byte[] using javascript and then POST it to the server to create a new file.

However, this approach is flawed. The server errors out if the the byte data is big. I followed the turorial and could not find a way to increase the limits. I did find ways to modify Web.Config file, but my WCF service does not has a web.config file.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: This may be better suited for Stack Overflow

Comment: Since the tutorial for setting up a wcf service based on SharePoint SharePoint, I thought it was best to post here. I will play around a bit, and post my results here. Because the way MSDN has that tutorial, I'm pretty sure a lot of people will have problem setting up configurations for the wcf service.

Comment: I know what you're saying, and the rules of these forums are kind of convoluted. However, this is more specifically about WCF and IIS than about SharePoint.

Comment: You might find there is a web.config, you should check in the c:\inetpub\wwwroot\wss\virtualdirectories\<your web>\web.config

Answer (score 2):

I solved this by creating a `Feature` and then add this code in `FeatureInstalled` method.

```
public override void FeatureInstalled(SPFeatureReceiverProperties properties)
{
    SPWebService contentService = SPWebService.ContentService;
    SPWcfServiceSettings wcfServiceSettings = new SPWcfServiceSettings();

    wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxStringContentLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxArrayLength = Int32.MaxValue;
    wcfServiceSettings.ReaderQuotasMaxBytesPerRead = Int32.MaxValue;
    wcfServiceSettings.MaxReceivedMessageSize = Int32.MaxValue;

    // Note: "runtime.svc" must be in lowercase
    contentService.WcfServiceSettings["runtime.svc"] = wcfServiceSettings;

    contentService.Update(true);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use web.config to change the settings for the SharePoint WCF services because the Factory classes referenced in the *.svc file do the configuration 'automatically'.

But you can use the SPWcfServiceSettings class to modify the quotas. (Note: This changes the quotas for all WCF services in the Farm that use the factory classes).

Here is an example on how to use the class: http://www.elumenotion.com/Blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=121

Comment: I ended up implementing a Geneirc Handler, which did not impose any limits. Since I'm working on a client project, I really don't want my WCF service quotas to affect all WCF services on the farm. Thanks for pointing that out though!

Comment: Where should I use SPWcfServiceSettings?

Answer (score 0):

I eneded up implementing a Generic Handler (.ashx), which did not impose any limits to the data I was POSTing.

If anyone is interested in ASHX handler in SharePoint, you can check out this article: http://www.lifeonplanetgroove.com/2010/10/15/adding-and-deploying-generic-handlers-ashx-to-a-sharepoint-2010-visual-studio-project/

I'm not sure why WCF didn't like my byte[], it was around 26KB.